# When pressing tab in Bash, display autocompleted filenames like in zsh or fish

Tags: command-line, bashrc, zsh, auto-completion, fish

Actually, I'm running `Bash`, and I'll like to make a settle modification at the configuration. With `zsh` and `fish`, we have the opportunity to display files and directories when we press Tab. Is there a mofication to `.bashrc` we could make to do similar thing?

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you say display, you mean print the file and directory names in the current directory, correct? Not literally print their contents?

Comment: @Seth In fact, with fish, when I press tab I obtain the picture I added in my question. If I press another time on tab, I could choose the `Desktop`, another time `Downloads`, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bind 'set show-all-if-ambiguous on'
bind 'TAB:menu-complete'
```

will get you close.  The only difference is it automatically appends the first result to your command, which is pretty annoying if the directory is fairly full (and there aren't any pretty colors).

source: [Bash autocomplete like zsh](https://superuser.com/q/288714/175675)

Comment: I install what you recommended, but It is still not working. I opened `.bashrc` such as I could copy-paste your two recommended lines. Once I did that, I reboot the system, and opened a new terminal window. When I pressed on tab, nothing happened. Is it normal?

Comment: @DavidHilbert hm, it might not work at an empty prompt. Try it with `cd`.

Comment: Yes, it works. (If you want) Do you have an idea how to select the file or directory, like fish, with a little bit of color?

Comment: @DavidHilbert I don't. Sorry.